# Working with three-dimensional panel data in Stata

Tags: stata, reshape, panel-data

I am working with three-dimensional macroeconomic panel data in Stata. My data is compiled from 51 issues of Economic Outlook(EO) from OECD, each containing data for up to 30 countries from 1960 up to 2010, where the first issue is from 1985 and the last issue is from 2010. The issues are released semiannualy and each issue has historic data as well as forecast 2 periods ahead. So for each variable there are essentially three subscripts: country (i), time the data is concerning (t), time the data was released (r).

I want to identify a fiscal policy shock as a forecast error: the forecast of public spending minus the realized value from the EO issue one period later. So, for the forecasted value, t=r-1, while for the realized value, t=r. For public spending, g, the forecast error should look like:

`g_i,t,r(t=r-1) - g_i,t,r(t=r)`
(if that makes sense).

I have never worked with three-dimensional panel data, so I don't know how to code with it. Currently my data looks like this:

```
time_str   value   frequency  location  variable  year  eo  year_half   eo_year  var_cat                                         eo_half  time_cal     time_eo tt_cal  tt_eo  id_cal id_eo time_actual
1970_1     16214   S          CAN       cg        1970  38  1           1985     Govt final cons expen, val, GDP exp approach    2        1970         1985.5  21      1      1      504   1970h1
1970_2     17046   S          CAN       cg        1970  38  2           1985     Govt final cons expen, val, GDP exp approach    2        1970.5       1985.5  22      1      1      530   1970h2
1971_1     17768   S          CAN       cg        1971  38  1           1985     Govt final cons expen, val, GDP exp approach    2        1971         1985.5  23      1      1      556   1971h1
1971_2     18968   S          CAN       cg        1971  38  2           1985     Govt final cons expen, val, GDP exp approach    2        1971.5       1985.5  24      1      1      582   1971h2
1972_1     19442   S          CAN       cg        1972  38  1           1985     Govt final cons expen, val, GDP exp approach    2        1972         1985.5  25      1      1      608   1972h1
1972_2     21140   S          CAN       cg        1972  38  2           1985     Govt final cons expen, val, GDP exp approach    2        1972.5       1985.5  26      1      1      634   1972h2
1973_1     22274   S          CAN       cg        1973  38  1           1985     Govt final cons expen, val, GDP exp approach    2        1973         1985.5  27      1      1      660   1973h1
1973_2     23800   S          CAN       cg        1973  38  2           1985     Govt final cons expen, val, GDP exp approach    2        1973.5       1985.5  28      1      1      686   1973h2
```

Some explanation of the data:

- tt_eo = id for EO issue. In the shown example all the data is from the first issue released in 1985
- tt_cal = id for the actual time (when the data is concerned)
- id_eo = id for each country-variable within each actual period (time of the release changes)
- id_cal = id for each country-variable within each EO issue (actual time for when the data is concerned changes)
- time_eo = time of release
- time_cal = actual time the data is concerned)

All my variables are not listed as variables but rather values of the variable "variable". Therefore I cannot generate anything or call on them, as Stata doesn't recognize them.
I have tried setting the data (see code below) but I still don't know how to work with the data.

```
*converting to time data and setting the time
gen time_actual = yh(year, year_half)
xtset id_cal time_actual, format(%th)
```

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to generate my forecast error variables (or generally how to work with this type of data)?

Comment: I would say reshape your date so that value is wide in actual, forecast 1 and forecast 2. This way you can set your panel to be identified by country and half-year period, while being able to easily `generate` forecast errors as the difference between actual and forecast`i`.

Comment: is there any indication, apart from when time_cal > time_eo, that a "value" is a forecast instead of an actual (realized) observation? - I believe it will be helpful to generate two variables, one "actual" for realized observations and one for "forecast" (which might take missings for the times when the data is given).

Comment: also, although you did a great job of explaining you data and problem, I believe that if you provide a sample of your data containing also a bit when time_cal > time_eo  (see `help input`) (and keeping only the minimum necessary columns) it will dramatically improve the chances and speed of getting a good and more concrete answer.